# TabRecent in Office 2016

Tags: c#, xml, office365

<idmso="TabRecent" visible ="false"> in Backstage Ribbon XML office 365 is making disable  the New button in office 365 Excel files. Is there any property to enable the NEW Button while hiding  TabRecent or open Button in Backstage Ribbon XML.

Comment: The TABRecent is to go back to a previous EXcel Files.  Until you go to two files you can't go back to a previous file.

Comment: <idmso="TabRecent" visible ="false"> working fine for office 2019. I just want to know its Microsoft problem that in office 365  When I hiding the Open tab using TabRecent  is disabled the New tab

Comment: Maybe a bug was fixed.  You cannot go backward if there is nothing to go backwards to.  So until you open more than one excel file there is no previous file.

Comment: My concern is  why New Tab is going Disable.

Comment: It starts disabled since there is no previous history.  Then after you open two excel files is goes enabled.

Comment: No, After openning two Excel files NEW not enabling . Actually  <idmso="TabRecent" visible ="false">  making NEW disable in Office 365 Pro Plus version 16  but its working Fine in  office 2019 Professional plus version 16 .My concern is this issue with Microsoft side or any other property will add for enabling the New Button in Xml with this tag